# Gatsby Link component is underlined, not sure why

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

```
import React from "react"
import Logo from "../images/logo.svg"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
const ListLink = props => (
<li style={{ display: `inline-block`, marginRight: `1rem` }}>
  <Link to={props.to}>{props.children}</Link>
</li>
)

export default function Layout({ children }) {
return (
<div style={{ margin: `1rem 1rem`, padding: `0 1rem` }}>
    <Link to = "/" style = {{textDecoration: "none"}}>
   <img src = {Logo} alt = "Logo" />
   </Link>
   <ul style={{ listStyle: `none`, float: `right`}}>
      <ListLink to="/">Home</ListLink>
      <ListLink to="/musings/">Musings</ListLink>
      <ListLink to="/books/">My Books</ListLink>
    </ul>
  {children}
</div>
)
}
```

Wondering why the links and impinge are underlined. I text-decoration = none but that doesn't work. Could someone help?

Comment: What does it mean "that doesn't work"? Are the styles correctly applied but override? Are not even applied?

Comment: I mean the hyperlinks are still underlined even after applying the style. It seems they are taking on the colour of the generic <a> tag but not sure how to override it.